# Is there a good spot to farm Health plants?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

There are a few plants that when collected fill up the green bar at the top. This is some easily accessible health while in combat.

But I always seem to be running low on these. Are there any spots that have a lot of them, or is there somewhere I can give some metal shards to fill it up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The medicinal herbs seem to occur everywhere at more less the same density. Possibly a bit higher near places where there are big fights. Nobody sells herbs.

Try to keep the bar full, and get the 'Herbalist' skill to double the size of the medicine pouch. Also Healer and Gatherer for faster healing and more resources.

Also don't forget the Health and Full-Health potions which heal quicker. Craft a larger pouch to carry more of these, You can buy these potions. Ypu can craft the health potions from rich / fatty / boney meat, so hunt animals and keep a stock of meat.

Comment: I do buy them, but it's starting to get expensive... (I'm bad at dodging and get hit a lot.)

Comment: You can craft the health potions as well from the various types of meat.

Comment: Dont worry. Boars and other wild life are shoot on sight :p

Comment: I think it's worth adding that the medicinal herbs tend to be more common along rivers besides just the big fights. I noticed it myself but I think it's also mentioned at one point in the game that rivers tend to have more of them.

Comment: Yeah, you know when you are in a 'story dungeon' and see health plans everywhere, there might be a boss incoming :p

Comment: Bunkers often have a lot of medicinal Gray Omen, but they're not usually dangerous unless you fall down an elevator shaft.